# Lowest Frequency De-excitation problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, hydrogen, atomic-excitation

Before the formation of the molecule it is possible for the muonic hydrogen
atom to be formed in an excited state and for radiation to be observed from
a single transition to the ground state. Calculate the lowest frequency
of the radiation that could be observed in this process and estimate the
momentum of the recoiling atom.

Muonic Hydrogen is 207 heavier than normal Hydrogen

To find the highest frequency I would use E=hf and solve for E_2 - E_1=hf , because this is the biggest gap. I don't even have a clue on how to start this question

Answer (score 1):

> Muonic Hydrogen is 207 heavier than normal Hydrogen

no, but the muon is 207 times heavier than the electron

> To find the highest frequency I would use E=hf and solve for E_2 - E_1=hf , because this is the biggest gap.

not really, n=2 to n=1 is the lowest frequency transition to the ground state

> I don't even have a clue on how to start this question

copy what Bohr did, but replace the electron mass with the muon mass